# Permission denied when trying to install inside a virtualenv using ansible

Tags: ansible

I have this play in my ansible playbook

```
- name: Setup virtualenv
  pip: 
    requirements="/vagrant/webapp/requirements/{{ requirements_filename }}" 
    virtualenv="$HOME/.envs/{{ project_name }}"
```

However, I am receiving a Permission denied error. It seems like ansible is trying to install the package into the system path and not into the virtualenv.

Here's the full traceback:

```
TASK: [deploy | Setup virtualenv] ********************************************* 
failed: [default] => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/pip install -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/dev.txt", "failed": true}
msg: stdout: New python executable in /home/vagrant/.envs/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Downloading/unpacking django>=1.8 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wsgiref>=0.1.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 4))
Downloading/unpacking django-allauth>=0.19.1 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 5))
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_vagrant/django-allauth/setup.py) egg_info for package django-allauth

Downloading/unpacking psycopg2>=2.6 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 6))
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_vagrant/psycopg2/setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2

Downloading/unpacking django-currencies>=0.3.3 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading django-currencies-0.3.3.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_vagrant/django-currencies/setup.py) egg_info for package django-currencies

Downloading/unpacking django-countries>=3.2 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 8))
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_vagrant/django-countries/setup.py) egg_info for package django-countries

Downloading/unpacking stripe>=1.22.1 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 9))
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_vagrant/stripe/setup.py) egg_info for package stripe

Downloading/unpacking pillow>=2.8.0 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 10))
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_vagrant/pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package pillow
    Single threaded build, not installing mp_compile: 1 processes

    warning: no files found matching 'LICENSE' under directory 'docs'
Downloading/unpacking django-compressor>=1.4 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 11))
Downloading/unpacking djangorestframework>=3.1.1 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 12))
Downloading/unpacking django-filter>=0.9.2 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 13))
  Downloading django_filter-0.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Obtaining formtools from git+https://github.com/django/django-formtools.git#egg=formtools (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 14))
  Cloning https://github.com/django/django-formtools.git to ./src/formtools
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/src/formtools/setup.py) egg_info for package formtools

  Installing extra requirements: 'egg'
Downloading/unpacking django-widget-tweaks>=1.3 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 15))
  Downloading django-widget-tweaks-1.3.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_vagrant/django-widget-tweaks/setup.py) egg_info for package django-widget-tweaks

Downloading/unpacking django-braces>=1.4.0 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 16))
  Downloading django_braces-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking django-debug-toolbar>=1.3.0 (from -r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/dev.txt (line 4))
Downloading/unpacking python-openid>=2.2.5 (from django-allauth>=0.19.1->-r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 5))
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_vagrant/python-openid/setup.py) egg_info for package python-openid

    warning: no files found matching 'CHANGELOG'
    warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'doc'
Downloading/unpacking requests-oauthlib>=0.3.0 (from django-allauth>=0.19.1->-r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading requests_oauthlib-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=1.0.3 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from django-allauth>=0.19.1->-r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 5))
Downloading/unpacking django-appconf>=0.4 (from django-compressor>=1.4->-r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 11))
  Downloading django_appconf-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from django-braces>=1.4.0->-r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 16))
Downloading/unpacking sqlparse (from django-debug-toolbar>=1.3.0->-r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/dev.txt (line 4))
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_vagrant/sqlparse/setup.py) egg_info for package sqlparse

Downloading/unpacking oauthlib>=0.6.2 (from requests-oauthlib>=0.3.0->django-allauth>=0.19.1->-r /vagrant/webapp/requirements/requirements.txt (line 5))
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_vagrant/oauthlib/setup.py) egg_info for package oauthlib

Installing collected packages: django, django-allauth, psycopg2, django-currencies, django-countries, stripe, pillow, django-compressor, djangorestframework, django-filter, formtools, django-widget-tweaks, django-braces, django-debug-toolbar, python-openid, requests-oauthlib, django-appconf, sqlparse, oauthlib
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 671, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 206, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 193, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destsubdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.dist-info'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/vagrant/.pip/pip.log


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Comment: For older Pythons, in the past this might have happened if the system folder contained the said package and `--no-site-packages` option was missing from virtualenv. Though `--no-site-packages` should have been the default for long time.

Comment: Also I suggest you update pip/virtualenv in your playbook before creating virtualenv. `command: sudo pip install -U pip virtualenv` should do it, I guess.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, tried upgrading pip and virtualenv before the play, but to no avail. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Is your Ansible up-to-date?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa, yes. I'm using Ansible `1.9.0.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the path explicitly and not using the `$HOME` variable.

```
- name: Setup virtualenv
  pip:
    virtualenv="/home/vagrant/.envs/{{ project_name }}"
    requirements="/vagrant/webapp/requirements/{{ requirements_filename }}"
```

Comment: If you want to use the HOME env variable you can still use `{{ lookup('env','HOME') }}`.

Using syntax like $HOME makes sense only when you are using it inside a string which is passed as argument to shell module. The pip module might not use shell commands behind the scenes to do its job; so variables like $HOME wont be expanded.

Comment: warning: `{{ lookup('env', 'HOME')}}` will be translated to the HOME environment variable of the host running the playbook; it may not be translated to the remote machine's HOME environment variable as you expect it. try running a remote playbook from a mac to a ubuntu server and `- debug: msg="{{ lookup('env', 'HOME') }}"` using ansible 1.9.0.1. use `{{ ansible_env.HOME }}` instead if you want the HOME variable for the remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying a `pip` executable path as well:

```
executable="$HOME/.envs/{{ project_name }}/bin/pip"
```

Didn't search for an exact reason TBH, but had to do the same to get stuff installed into virtual environments. Seemed like it tried to install into a virtual environment using global `pip`. Maybe that's possible to do under some circumstances, wasn't my case.

Comment: This assumes that the virtualenv already exists before the play, right?

Comment: @RodXavier I think not, should be doable in one step.

Comment: tried your answer but it gives me this error `msg: Failed to find required executable $HOME/.envs/venv/bin/pip`

Comment: @RodXavier Just tested with Ansible `1.9.0.1`, created virtual environment and installed packages from `requirements.txt`, went through alright in one step. Other than *"check your paths"* I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the pip module is using the system Python so it will try and install the package on the expected system path to `site-packages` and since you're not running this as root or using sudo it can't write to '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/...'

I'm assuming you want to install the pip package under the virtualenv, correct?

If so beware that Ansible modules always use, by default, the system default Python interpreter unless you set `ansible_python_interpreter`.
An example of how to do this can be found on [Best way to always run ansible inside a virtualenv on remote machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575084/best-way-to-always-run-ansible-inside-a-virtualenv-on-remote-machines)

A link to a short discussion about the subject and why Ansible people don't want to change `#!/usr/bin/python` for the more virtualenv-friendly `#!/usr/bin/env python` can be found [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/1062#issuecomment-88718422).

As a note you'll have the same problem if you're running Ansible from a local virtualenv and try and use say `ec2` module without having `boto` installed at the system-level (but installed at the virtualenv level).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is using `/usr/bin/pip`, not `pip` from virtualenv. Not sure why this happens - a bug in Ansible? Can you manually check your virtualenv has `pip` command? One thing I can think out from my head `pip` is created for root (sudo) and you try to run the command as a normal user and it doesn't have read access to virtualenv'ed pip.

You can probably use pip manually like this for workaround.

```
- name: Create virtualenv for app using chosen Python
  shell: virtualenv --python=python3.4 {{deploy_location}}/venv
  sudo: yes

- name: Install Python packages
  sudo: yes
  command: {{deploy_location}}/venv/bin/pip -r {{deploy_location}}/requirements.txt
```