# Register a pip installed package in conda environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, ansible, conda

I am working on a project where they are using Ansible to run several conda installs.  I need to install two additional packages from github that have dependencies that are already covered by the existing conda installs **with the second package having a dependency on the first**.

Using the Ansible code below, I can get the first package to install without reinstalling the dependencies.

```
- name: install mypackage 
    shell: /home/myname/envs/myproject/bin/pip install --install-option="--prefix=/home/myname/envs/myproject" --egg https://github.com/myname/mypackage/archive/my_branch.zip
```

This gets me 95% of the way there, however, when I try to install the second package, it doesn't recognize the first package as having been installed and fails.

I am new to this and I have been throwing things up against the wall but I'm not able to install the first package in such a way where:

- It recognizes the existing conda installs
- The second package identifies the first one

Comment: I'm also open to suggestions on title.  I don't love this one but couldn't think of anything better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can understand from your task you are using a venv to install the packages, that's good. I don't understand why, though, you are using the shell module to handle the install.. This not good. 
You can handle all this with ansible'  `pip` module :

```
- name: "Install mypackage"
  pip:
    virtualenv: /home/{{ lookup('env','USER') }}/envs/myproject/
    name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
     - "https://github.com/myname/mypackage1/archive/my_branch.zip"
     - "https://github.com/myname/mypackage2/archive/my_branch.zip"
```

This should install correctly the packages in the order you require, without the hassle of having to work your way through `shell` output.

Note that you can mix normal python packages with eggs etc..

As an alternative to `virtualenv` you can use `executable`.

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pip_module.html)

Comment: This looks awesome.  I admittedly have no idea what I am doing and I am emulating what some other people did.  Let me try this out but I am going to accept it for now.

Comment: I will be very sad if that doesn't work.. :( You could paste whatever error pip comes out with though, it might not be related to ansible

Comment: `msg: [Errno 13] Permission denied`.  Also, {{ item }} needed to be wrapped in quotes (Ansible's error message was amazingly well written btw).  Would have edited myself but it needed to be at least 6 char for me to edit.

Comment: I think it might be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668129/permission-denied-when-trying-to-install-inside-a-virtualenv-using-ansible

Comment: Yes, sorry for the `{{ item }}`. To install to your `/home` you will probably need to `su` to yourself ( or whatever user you are using ) with `become: myname`

Comment: The code worked great with the edits I added :).  Thanks, this is better than I had hoped to find!

Comment: The edit looks great, only thing to be aware is that by using `lookup` you will  install the venv + packages in the home of the user ansible is running with. I'm happy to see you found a solution ;)

Comment: Yup, that's the intention here.  We are on a shared server where none of us have admin.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the question is how to use ansible to `pip install` packages within a `conda` environment. Noting that it is [perfectly possible to use `pip install` within a conda environment](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment), which is particularly useful in cases where the desired package does not exist on the conda repositories and cannot be installed with `conda install`.

The goal is thus to use the environment created by `conda`, and **not** a `virtualenv` (for which, btw, ansible's pip module provides specific parameters).

I have managed to do so by using [ansible's pip module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pip_module.html) and **pointing the pip `executable` to the one installed within the desired conda environment**.

See code below, notice usage of the `executable` variable:

```yaml
- name: Install pip packages WITHIN a designated conda environment
  pip:
    name: some_package_name
    executable: "/home/[username]/[anaconda3]/envs/[conda_env_name]/bin/pip"
    # ^-- Of course you will need to ensure the correct path.
```

This will `pip install` the packages inside the designated conda environment.