# Shade (python) module used by ansible needed but installed from yum not pip.

Tags: ansible, openstack

## hi,

i am learning Openstack Newton and i'm building a lab. I have a pc which serves as controller and a Dell PowerEdge 2950 which will serve as compute node. I have another computer which will be the Ansible node. I made my first ansible playbook and tried to run it on the controller but i get an error (i need shade module installed on controlled).

Here is the problem. If i install shade using pip it messes with my openstack controller and the horizon dashboard is not accesible anymore, i get http error 500.

Is there a shade module in yum and how is it called?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) to separate python contexts.

So create a virtualenv, activate it, install ansible and any necessary library (without messing up with the system python libraries) and launch ansible.

If you don't want to use ansible in a virtualenv, you can create one just for the task execution by setting `ansible_python_interpreter` for localhost (take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578760/439790)).

Comment: hi, after a few days of trying i have the following results. shade module installed via pip is replacing some modules used by openstack and the dashboard and glance service is not working anymore. I dont need the ansible on virtualenv, i only need the shade module to be on a virtualenv. so  i built it. On the controller computer i have a virtualenv with only shade isntalled and requirments. My problem is: How does ansible playbook knows to acces my shade module from virtualenv? maybe i should post a question about this.

Comment: If you want the module to use your virtualenv with shade library, just play with the `ansible_python_interpreter` and take a look at the answer pointed in the last sentence of my answer.